# Reload Partial View

Tags: partial-views

I'm having trouble reloading a partial view after an ajax success. My partial view is stored in

```
<div id="partial">@Html.Partial("_Departments", Model)</div>
```

This is in the index of the Department view

I'm trying this (which obviously isn't working)

```
$("#partial").load('@Url.Action("Index", "_Departments")');
```

How can I reload the partial view, everything else is fine as when I refresh the page I get the expected results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this working with help from a colleague of mine...

In my controller I had to return the html for the partial view in the Json response.

```
return Json(new { Success = true, Msg = "Field successfully added", html = RenderPartialViewToString("_IndexTable", returnModel) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Also had to create a BaseController class with the method for the **RenderPartialViewToString**

```
public string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
    {
        ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(this.ControllerContext, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(this.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

The finally in my View had to add the following line

```
$("#partial").html(data.html);
```